# Buttons on a title bar

Tags: android, button, menuitem

I have two buttons on my title bar, titlebar.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/itemBack"
    android:icon="@drawable/back"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/btnBack">"
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/itemAdd"
    android:icon="@drawable/add"
    android:showAsAction="always">
</item>
</menu>
```

This is a part of my activity file:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recipes, menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.titlebar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

How can I put a inscription not on a left or right side of button, but only on button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean  [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). And search in web before you post anything here. ;) Good Luck!

And for ActionBar use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

In xml file write.

```
android:icon="@string/YourID"
```

And in string.xml write your id and text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by inscription, but if you want to add text to a Button then you just need to simply add this to your xml

android:text="somestring"